# How open file PDF exclusively with Adobe reader?

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-studio-2.0

in my method viewPDF(), how can i write code to open PDF exclusively with Adobe reader and not with other PDF app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try {
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
   intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(myFile), "application/pdf");
   startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityNotFoundException) {

  final String appPackageName = "com.adobe.reader";
  try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
   } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
   }
}
```

Comment: But with intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader"), PDF is open with Adobe reader online version or with app? I need app

Comment: it will open with the app

Comment: And if people have not installed app, if i want link app in google play to help them?

Comment: What happens if the user has Acrobat?

Comment: the pdf should be opened in the app

Comment: @TomerShemesh it doesn't work....see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675603/how-open-pdf-file-exclusively-with-adobe-reader

Comment: @TomerShemesh if i have more than one app to open PDF, smartphone make me choose app to open PDF and not open PDF directly with Adobe reader....why?